# Making and restoring image of one OS in multiboot setup

Tags: linux, windows, backup, multi-boot, restore

Linux is easy. Just restore all partitions and then use [boot repair](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/). Windows has this boot partition and this is the real problem for me. Should I backup it for each Windows image? Or can I omit it and repair it with Windows Repair CD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered, I'll do it myself. You can even create windows boot partition from scratch. You just need Windows Repair Disc or Installation Disc (easier to get, even on different OS).

1. Boot from your DVD/USB and click repair computer -> advanced -> command prompt or just Shift+F10.
2. If boot partition doesn't exist, create it with `diskpart`.
3. Make boot partition active (again in `diskpart`).
4. Copy `bootmgr` from DVD/USB to boot partition if it's not there.
5. Run:

   ```
   bootrec /fixmbr
   bootrec /fixboot
   bootrec /rebuildbcd
   ```

Now it should work like a charm. You can skip `bootrec /fixmbr` if you have grub installed. In this case you need to use [boot repair](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) afterwards.